# How to add the gradient to Chakra UI Progress?

Tags: chakra-ui

I am trying to set the gradient to the Progress component of Chakra UI, but it doesn't support background image change. Any idea how I can achieve this or is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question - [How do I ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - thanks

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this recently and used the `sx` prop to style the actual `div` for the Progress bar.

```
<Progress
  height="24px"
  borderRadius="2xl"
  value={60}
  sx={{
    '& > div': {
      background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(43,108,176,1) 10%, rgba(66,153,225,1) 90%)',
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Progress
   bgGradient="linear(gray.300,yellow.400,pink.200)"
/>
```