# In Chakra UI how to build a divider that uses a background image?

Tags: svg, background-image, chakra-ui, divider

In Styled Components to build a `div` separator that implements an image background I've used:

```
const Separator = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.normal};
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,code');
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.primary};
  height: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small};
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
`
```

but when looking at Chakra's [`Divider`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/divider/theming) I'm not seeing a way to use a background image as the divider and this approach did not work:

```
<Divider
  backgroundRepeat="repeat-x"
  height="1rem"
  opacity="1"
  backgroundImage={`url('data:image/svg+xml,code')`}
/>
```

### Research

- [How to add the gradient to Chakra UI Progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590038/how-to-add-the-gradient-to-chakra-ui-progress)
- [How to change the background color of the Chakra UI Progress component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011761/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-chakra-ui-progress-component)
- [React Create a Horizontal Divider with Text In between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730527/react-create-a-horizontal-divider-with-text-in-between)
- [Chakra UI Image component not recognizing image path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339712/chakra-ui-image-component-not-recognizing-image-path)

In Chakra what is the correct approach to building a div separator that uses a background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure out how with adding [`sx`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/the-sx-prop) prop:

Because `Divider` has an added `opacity` and `border` wrote the divider as:

```
<Divider
  opacity="1"
  border="none"
  mb="5"
  sx={{
    bgRepeat: 'repeat-x',
    height: 2,
    bgColor: 'color2.600',
    bgPosition: '25% 75%',
    maskImage: `url(
      'data:image/svg+xml,code'
    )`,
  }}
/>
```

but when looking at [`Background`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#background) props `bgPosition` doesn't seem to work in the scenario with `sx`.